# Getting org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException with Transactions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

So I am currently trying to build a non-trivial small contact system, just to get my head around Hibernate, JPA, and Spring Boot a bit better.

Basically when I try to run this through spring boot:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/contact")
public class ContactController {
    @Autowired
    private ContactService service;

    /*
     * This method will list all existing Contacts.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/list" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Contact> listContacts() {
        return service.getAllContacts();
    }
}
```

where

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service("contactServices")
@Transactional
public class ContactService implements I_ContactService{
    @Autowired
    private ContactDao contactDao;

    @Override
    public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        return contactDao.getAllContacts();
    }

}
```

is my service, I get the following StackTrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.platform.contact.ContactService com.platform.contact.ContactController.service; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.platform.contact.ContactService field com.platform.contact.ContactController.service to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.platform.Application.main(Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.platform.contact.ContactService com.platform.contact.ContactController.service; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.platform.contact.ContactService field com.platform.contact.ContactController.service to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.platform.contact.ContactService field com.platform.contact.ContactController.service to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Now this doesn't appear to be the case when I change ContactService in the controller to the interface I_ContactService (which I know is technically what I should do since it helps to enforce the dependency injection advantages and what not, but for the moment I'm just playing around so didn't think this would be an issue), and when the interface is used, the build and deployment all work fine, and localhost is happy to respond with information about my db.

Although I know I have found A solution, I would like to know the reasoning behind why its throwing the issue with the proxy. I do understand that the proxy is how the AOP portion of Spring is implemented, I found that out on another post which I can't find it seems now, but I can't understand why its such an issue now, this being more confusing as I have a similar class which I use for title, which went smoothly and without a hiccup.

I haven't included the Contact.java file here, or the ContactDao implementation since I made (albeit a dangerous) assumption this is unrelated, but please correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

Spring creates proxy for `ContactService` when you mark it as `@Transactional`.The proxy implements `I_ContactService` not `ContactService`. To understand more, check this [link](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/23/transactions-caching-and-aop-understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring).

Comment: Thank you so much, that explains everything I could have thought to ask and more. Brilliant